# Running Singularity container without root as different user inside

Tags: linux, docker, hpc, wine, singularity-container

I am trying to run a Docker container with Singularity that executes a Windows program (msconvert from proteowizard) via Wine. This image: https://hub.docker.com/r/chambm/pwiz-skyline-i-agree-to-the-vendor-licenses

The Wine installation inside the Docker container is owned by *root*. Running with Singularity on a standard user account with

`singularity run --env WINEDEBUG=-all pwiz.sif wine msconvert`

results in:

`wine: '/wineprefix64' is not owned by you`

So I must use the `--fakeroot` option to overcome this.

HOWEVER, on the remote HPC system I wish to run the container I cannot use `--fakeroot` because it is not allowed by the system admins:

`FATAL:   while extracting pwiz.sif: root filesystem extraction failed: extract command failed: FATAL:   configuration disallows users from running sandbox based containers`

My workaround is to add a `%post` to build the container and change the ownership of the  directory to the user of the remote system, then rebuild the Singularity image on a machine I have root access. Simply:

```
Bootstrap: docker
From: chambm/pwiz-skyline-i-agree-to-the-vendor-licenses
%post
useradd -u 1234 user
chown -Rf --no-preserve-root user /wineprefix64
```

This works for me. But my question is, is there a better way to generalise this so any unprivileged user can run this without having to manually re-build it for their username?

Comment: A possible solution is to make a copy to the folder owned by a non root user.

`ORIGINAL_PREFIX=${WINEPREFIX}; WINEPREFIX=$(mktemp -d wineprefix); export WINEPREFIX; for file in ${ORIGINAL_PREFIX}/*; do ln -sT ${file} ${WINEPREFIX}/$(basename ${file}); done`